# Return a value based on multiple conditions in Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have the following table where I want to return the **Price** of a selected **Item Name** based on 2 conditions - (1) date, (2) item name.

Does anyone know if index match would provide an output for this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You also can use `INDEX`/`MATCH` functions. If dates or items are not unique it will return first match.

```
=INDEX($B$8:$D$13,MATCH($B$2,$A$8:$A$13,0),MATCH($B$1,$B$7:$D$7,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the sumproduct function is one way you can achieve this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($D$8:$F$8=$D$3)*($C$9:$C$15=$D$4)*$D$9:$F$15)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the advice. It's interesting to know that sumproduct works!

Comment: this would work as long as your date column has unique entries else it will sum same date rows